Definition of the phrase 寬幽
我住的房子面對一條寬幽大街。
I've never seen this phrase before, but according to online dictionaries:
寬 = wide
幽 = deep in an emotional/spiritual sense
So I can understand the street is physically wide. But 幽 here trips me up. It doesn't mean physically deep, but rather a feeling of depth related to emotions. This is where I'm not understanding this phrase. Thanks for the help.

It often appears in real estate ads. e.g. 三房一廳，空間寬闊，環境幽靜 --> 一千平方呎寬幽套房

幽 - 隱蔽(secluded; hidden from view with implication of quiet)
寬幽大街 is similar to the "Avenue(林蔭大道)" which is a relatively wide roadway with tall trees planted on the sides. When located in a residential district, the traffic volume and speed are low, thus, it is quieter than the main street in the business district.

No need to get mystical or emotional!
宽广的：wide
幽：幽静：隐蔽的地方
serene: peaceful: secluded (and therefore hidden) place
我住的房子面對一條寬幽大街。
I live in a wide (but) quiet street.

幽：secluded, dim
宽幽: wide/spacious (宽) to the point that it looks almost deserted/desolate (幽).
It sounds like the street is possibly too big for the level of traffic it was meant to make space for, so it always looks bare and very quiet (almost too quiet).
